# Convert date column to columns 'start' and 'end' using regex

Tags: regex, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with some text and dates as strings.

```
pd.DataFrame({'dates': ['start 01.01.2020',                      # Only start date
                        'start 10.10.2019, end 20.20.2019', 
                        '01.05.2019',                            # Only start date
                        '01.11.2019-04.11.2019']})
```

I want to create two new columns; `start` and `end`. Some rows have both *start* and *end date*, but some rows only have *start date*. For rows with only start date, the start and end date is the same.

The resulting table should look like this:

[image]

So far I've tried to extract the dates using regex, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "dates": [
            "start 01.01.2020",  # Only start date
            "start 10.10.2019, end 20.20.2019",
            "01.05.2019",  # Only start date
            "01.11.2019-04.11.2019",
        ]
    }
)

df[["start", "end"]] = (
    df["dates"].str.extractall(r"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)").unstack().ffill(axis=1)
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                              dates       start         end
0                  start 01.01.2020  01.01.2020  01.01.2020
1  start 10.10.2019, end 20.20.2019  10.10.2019  20.20.2019
2                        01.05.2019  01.05.2019  01.05.2019
3             01.11.2019-04.11.2019  01.11.2019  04.11.2019
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is a bit longer. But it should be easier to understand what happens.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "dates": [
            "start 01.01.2020",  # Only start date
            "start 10.10.2019, end 20.20.2019",
            "01.05.2019",  # Only start date
            "01.11.2019-04.11.2019",
        ]
    }
)

pattern = r'\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\d\d'
pattern_object = re.compile(pattern)

for index in df.index:  # loop over each line
    current_line = df.loc[index, "dates"]  # get the current line as string
    dates_per_line = pattern_object.findall(current_line)  # extract the dates as a list
    if len(dates_per_line) == 2:  # two elements: start and end is given
        df.loc[index, "start"] = dates_per_line[0]  # first element ist start
        df.loc[index, "end"] = dates_per_line[1]  # second element is end
    elif len(dates_per_line) == 1:  # if only one element: use it for start and end
        df.loc[index, "start"] = dates_per_line[0]
        df.loc[index, "end"] = dates_per_line[0]
```