# How can convert struct column timestamp with start and end into normal pythonic stamp column?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a time-series pivot table with struct timestamp column including `start` and `end` of time frame of records as follow:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 400)
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': ['{"start":"2022-01-19T00:00:00.000+0000","end":"2022-01-20T00:00:00.000+0000"}'],
                   "X1": [25],
                   "X2": [33],
                   })
df 
#                                                                       timestamp   X1  X2
#0  {"start":"2022-01-19T00:00:00.000+0000","end":"2022-01-20T00:00:00.000+0000"}   25  33
```

Since later I will use timestamps as the index for time-series analysis, I need to convert it into timestamps with just `end`/`start`.
I have tried to find the solution using regex maybe unsuccessfully based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68988809/10452700) as follows:

```py
df[["start_timestamp", "end_timestamp"]] = (
    df["timestamp"].str.extractall(r"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)").unstack().ffill(axis=1)
)
```

but I get:

> ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

so I try to reach following expected dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': ['{"start":"2022-01-19T00:00:00.000+0000","end":"2022-01-20T00:00:00.000+0000"}'],
                   'start_timestamp': ['2022-01-19T00:00:00.000+0000'],
                   'end_timestamp': ['2022-01-20T00:00:00.000+0000'],
                   "X1": [25],
                   "X2": [33]})
df 
#                                                                       timestamp   start_timestamp                 end_timestamp                   X1  X2
#0  {"start":"2022-01-19T00:00:00.000+0000","end":"2022-01-20T00:00:00.000+0000"}   2022-01-19T00:00:00.000+0000    2022-01-20T00:00:00.000+0000    25  33
```

Comment: Maybe `df[["start_timestamp", "end_timestamp"]] = df["timestamp"].str.extract(r'"start":"([^"]*)","end":"([^"]+)')` will be enough?

Comment: It is more than enough, actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract both values with an `extract` call:

```py
df[["start_timestamp", "end_timestamp"]] = df["timestamp"].str.extract(r'"start":"([^"]*)","end":"([^"]+)')
```

The `"start":"([^"]*)","end":"([^"]+)` regex matches `"start":"`, then captres any zero or more chars other than `"` into Group 1 (the `start` column value) and then matches `","end":"` and then captures one or more chars other than `"` into Group 2 (the `end` column value).

Also, if the data you have is valid JSON, you can parse the JSON instead of using a regex:

```py
def extract_startend(x):
    j = json.loads(x)
    return pd.Series([j["start"], j["end"]])

df[["start_timestamp", "end_timestamp"]] = df["timestamp"].apply(extract_startend)
```

Output of `print(df.to_string())`:

```
                                                                   timestamp  X1  X2               start_timestamp                 end_timestamp
0  {"start":"2022-01-19T00:00:00.000+0000","end":"2022-01-20T00:00:.........  25  33  2022-01-19T00:00:00.000+0000  2022-01-20T00:00:00.000+0000
```

Comment: Thanks for your input I also tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68989278/10452700) but in the end I couldn't manage to include the desired columns.

Comment: @Mario I also added a JSON parsing approach.

Comment: I have also one question since I'm using `"start":"2022-01-19T00:00:00.000+0000","end":"2022-01-20T00:00:00.000+0000"` this type of timestamp, for time-series processing, is there any way to keep both the start and end of the observed record and use it as index? or we need to keep *only* start or end for pandas dataframe? bcz if I index timestamp including `start` and `end` perse within pandas dataframe, I might not use it as index for time-series analsis.

Comment: @Mario No idea, once you extracted the values, you may do whatever you need with them.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient approach, but it works:

```
df[['start_timestamp','end_timestamp']]=df['timestamp'].str.split(',',expand=True)
df['start_timestamp']=df['start_timestamp'].str.extract('(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}T\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{3}\+\d{4})')
df['end_timestamp']=df['end_timestamp'].str.extract('(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}T\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{3}\+\d{4})')
```